# Mobile First - How to segmentate logs depending on the session

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, java.util.logging, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

I'm working on a mobile banking solution using Mobile First v 7.0 and one of the requirements is to isolate the customer's logs in a dedicated log file which gets created once a session is started to track all the details by session.
Is it possible to do such thing ?

I'm using Liberty profile v 8.5 and I wonder if it's handled in Liberty or there is something which can be done from Mobile First perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to MobileFirst but to the underlying application server that handles the logs creation. AFAIK not WebSphere full profile nor WebSphere Liberty profile provide the ability to separate logs based on their contents.

What you could do is create your own tool/script that will go over the messages.log file and will copy out log lines to another file based on the specific prefixes (the number that denotes that type of the log line, for example "123456E"). There is no ready list of such prefixes, but you can find them on your own in the messages.log file.

Comment: Ok thanks Idan, I wanted a confirmation that it's not possible.