# Worklight 6.2 - Server side WL.Logger

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying configure server logs on worklight runtime environment 6.2 (deployed on WAS 8.5)

Is it possible to configure and format the **WL.Logger** output on server side in order to:

- Log on a differtent file than standard output
- Use a **conversion pattern layout** (similar to the log4j one):

> e.g. [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}],   %p, %c, %m%n

- specify a rolling behavior (size, filename format, ...)

Alternatively, is it possible to use log4j? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638172/mobile-first-how-to-segmentate-logs-depending-on-the-session) about using different files for log output.
   Short answer: not something Worklight controls.
2. log4j was replaced with the standard logging mechanisms provided by WebSphere.